# Fatal error. Array index out of range in indexpath - swift

Tags: ios, swift

My following code is part of a search controller. It works without a problem but after 8-10 searches, I encounter fatal error (Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION) on following line :

```
let movie = filteredMovies[indexPath.item]
```

Could you please advise the way of solving this kind of problems.

```
extension searchResults: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("searchCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! searchResultCell

    let movie = filteredMovies[indexPath.item]
    cell.searchLabel.text = movie.title

    let fileUrl = NSURL(string: movie.thumb)!

    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: fileUrl)
    {
        cell.searchImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
        cell.searchImage.image = UIImage(data: data)


        //  to make images rounded
        cell.searchImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.searchImage.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
        cell.searchImage.clipsToBounds = true

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int

{

  return filteredMovies.count

}
```

}

Comment: Show a stack trace and the contents of the array at the time of the crash

Comment: Are you mutating the array `filteredMovies` without reloading the tableview? We can only guess here since we don't know what's happening to `filteredMovies`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `indexPath.item` is within the bounds of the array `filteredMovies`:

```
if (indexPath.item >= 0 || indexPath.item < movie.count) {

    // now you can safely use filteredMovies[indexPath.item]

} else {
    // print something so you can investigate
}
```

And if you wonder why `indexPath.item` might be out of the bounds of `filteredMovies`, it's other programming logic you have to investigate (maybe you remove some elements in `filteredMovies` after the tableView is loaded).

After all, always checking the bounds is a good thing when you have doubt or want to make sure it will never cause crash (fault tolerance concept).